# How can I add "/" to my Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, text, match

I have a regex control that,

```
Regex.IsMatch(inputText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ-]+$").
```

And I want to add the `/` character to it. I have tried these,

```
  Regex.IsMatch(inputText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ-/]+$")
  Regex.IsMatch(inputText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ-\/]+$")
  Regex.IsMatch(inputText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ-//]+$")
```

They are not crashing my application. How can I add it?

Comment: Add it before `-`, ex.: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ/-]+$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you do not have the `-` at the end. The `-` denotes a range, and in your case, you are specifying a ranged between `İ` and `/` which is invalid. To fix this, simply move the `-` at the end, like so:

```
        string inputText = "asdfdfdfsd/";
        System.Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(inputText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9üÜşŞçÇöÖıİ/-]+$"));
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Yields:

```
True
```

Comment: But I want a range from بى to  จัก :) +1

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay: You're welcome. As a general rule of thumb, the `-` should always be placed last when used within square brackets :).